# how to replicate a guided send through the SFMC api

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk

One of our teams is looking to automate their send process - at the moment they do a guided send in the SFMC UI to send a email to a DE.  What I've been trying to work out is which API objects I should be using to send an email to a Data Extension. I think I need to create a SendDefninition and then do a triggered send, but I don't seem to be able to add suppression lists like this and I can in a guided send.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: If this is a scheduled repetitive event, you can create a User Initiated send (allows Suppression lists) and put it in a scheduled automation. This automation could also be used as a trigger via an API call to run the automation. (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140001/starting-automation-program-using-soap-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Guided Send is created and sent through the SOAP API using the EmailSendDefinition with Create or Perform SoapActions/Methods. A good place to see examples of both creating and performing EmailSendDefintions is available in the [developer documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_performing_and_deleting_email_send_definitions.htm). The document shows sending to data extensions and using exclusion lists.

**Sample SOAP Envelopes from Documentation:**

Perform SOAP Envelope

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-30851894" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:To>https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</wsa:To>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:FAB69169EC56A8F9D51228490514867</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:Action>Retrieve</wsa:Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options></Options>
            <Action>start</Action>
            <Definitions>
                <Definition xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:EmailSendDefinition">
                    <q1:ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></q1:ObjectID>
                    <q1:CustomerKey>7dc973cc-e0ab-4aec-9ba8-cf0b739e02dc</q1:CustomerKey>
                    <q1:Name>ESD_Name_7dc973cc-e0ab-4aec-9ba8-cf0b739e02dc</q1:Name>
                    <q1:Description>ESD_Desc_7dc973cc-e0ab-4aec-9ba8-cf0b739e02dc</q1:Description>
                    <q1:SendClassification>
                        <q1:ObjectID>51422ad6-6f65-de11-bf42-001e0bbb7678</q1:ObjectID>
                    </q1:SendClassification>
                    <q1:SendDefinitionList>
                        <q1:ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></q1:ObjectID>
                        <q1:CustomerKey>SDL CustomerKey</q1:CustomerKey>
                        <q1:SendDefinitionListType>SourceList</q1:SendDefinitionListType>
                        <q1:CustomObjectID>729860f8-7d66-de11-bf42-001e0bbb7678</q1:CustomObjectID>
                        <q1:DataSourceTypeID>CustomObject</q1:DataSourceTypeID>
                        <q1:Name>SDL Name</q1:Name>
                    </q1:SendDefinitionList>
                    <q1:Email>
                        <q1:ID>123</q1:ID>
                        <q1:ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></q1:ObjectID>
                    </q1:Email>
                    <q1:EmailSubject>ESD Email Subject</q1:EmailSubject>
                    <q1:Additional>cb99f3b1-67a4-452a-94c0-886e9a930961</q1:Additional>
                </Definition>
            </Definitions>
        </PerformRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

SOAP Request for Starting Email Send Definition

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-28677619" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Action>start</Action>
         <Definitions>
            <Definition xsi:type="ns1:EmailSendDefinition" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <CustomerKey>Market2Lead_Email_Definition_Key</CustomerKey>
            </Definition>
         </Definitions>
      </PerformRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```