# run automation SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, automationstudio

I have created a automation with script activity which i need to run it through SOAP API. when i pass the payload i get a response as 200 ok but the automation is not running. Below is the payload.`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181"
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>abhishekmishra</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Welcome@123</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Action>start</Action>
            <Definitions>
                <Definition xsi:type="Automation">
                    <ObjectID>109309d6-17ce-4724-94eb-209ecce255e7</ObjectID>
                </Definition>
            </Definitions>
        </PerformRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

**SAMPLE RESPONSE**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>ExecuteResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:2645bf96-9567-4659-826b-0df5ac4df48b</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:ad5b5417-4241-4a57-b334-8af3b6699108</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-f60699b4-f89d-46b9-b9ae-041a11b6c7de">
                <wsu:Created>2018-08-29T10:09:16Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-08-29T10:14:16Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ExecuteResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>a3bc5995-2ff3-4eee-9efb-a54ae0337efe</RequestID>
        </ExecuteResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: what is the state of your automation? If your automation has been paused then it is a known behavior that API call won't start/run the automation and from my tests, I have seen that you're able to start/run automation if they are active or source isn't configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a similar topic, it may be that you are not sending the `Perform` action with your request.

Check the linked and resolved question here [Starting Automation Using SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140001/starting-automation-program-using-soap-api?rq=1).