# SFMC Automation using API - I am not aiming to start the automation which contains a query activity and journey entry event

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, automation, alert

I am setting up an automation which needs to start when an API call is made.

1. This automation will have to run a query that populates a DE.
2. This DE is then used in a journey

Background:
We are planning to run journey based on weather alerts. Idea is the weather application will trigger alerts to an end point and when an alert is received, two api calls will happen.
One of them will populate a DE with weather details. The other will have to initiate the automation.

Hoping for the best minds to pitch in.

Comment: Hi, sounds reasonable so far. What have you tried / researched so far? What is the question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi @JonasLamberty, I have no clue how to initiate the automation using API call. This is the blocker for now.

Comment: Hi, you can do this via SOAP API. I just entered "automation API" into the search, there is a lot about this sort of process on this community. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230490/run-automation-soap-api

Also, this: https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-starting-an-automation-with-ssjs/

Comment: What level of frequency are you expecting on this? If its more often then once per 30 minutes, you will want to find a different approach as this will lead to failures and such a heavy process draw it could slow down your entire instance

Comment: @Gortonington, thanks for the reply. I am assuming it won't be more than once in 30mins.