# Is it possible to run an automation only when a data extension is re-populated with data? Not knowing when data is coming

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, api, sql, automation

**Background:** Currently, we have an automation job where audience is pushed to FTP and automation trigger is based on file drop. When file is pushed with a set naming convention on FTP, automation triggers that imports the audience in DE and subsequent queries run for additional segmentation on that audience.

**Question:** We are exploring the API option to populate the data extension instead of pushing file to FTP but the issue is, how we will know when to trigger the automation so subsequent queries can be run? In this case, we DO NOT know when data will be populated in DE via API, there is no consistent time frame each month.

Also - In this case, DE that will hold the imported audience won't be cleared. Each month when new data is pushed by API, it will override the existing data.

Any way to trigger / run the automation only when a data extension is re-populated? or if there is another way to run / configure some sql scripts that will only run when a data extension is re-populated?

Comment: Is it critical to only run the automation when the information is received? Would it be possible to set up multiple automation and schedule them so that they run at a 15 minute interval?

And if API is an option, can you just trigger the automation on the other end?

Comment: Unfortunately, API is only being used to push the data, no other API to trigger an automation is an option. Data folks handles the data push to tables while goal is to create something that will work with their data push.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option can be fired the automation via SOAP API once all the records were imported.

[Starting Automation Program using SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140001/starting-automation-program-using-soap-api?rq=1)